# MySQL: ошибка добавления пользователя при установке

Tags: mysql

Всем привет!

Я установил MySQL8.0.29 Windows 8.1. Все прошло без ошибок, но в окне Apply Configuration выскакивает ошибка на этапе Creating Accounts (пишет в логе):

Beginning configuration step: Creating user accounts

Attempting to Add New MySQL Users
An error occurred trying to add new users to the MySQL database (see log).
Ended configuration step: Creating user accounts

В итоге конфигурация MySQL просто прерывается. В мастере установки я уже добавил одного пользователя, себя то есть. Может этого достаточно?

Comment: А что мы видим в результате выполнения рекомендации *(see log)*?

Comment: То есть - что видим? Там собственно рекомендации нет.

Comment: Ну вообще-то было обращение к MySQL. И если произошла ошибка, то как минимум надо сунуть нос в Error Log самого MySQL. А ещё лучше - предварительно включить General Log и посмотреть в деталях, что именно, какие команды, конфигуратор посылал на сервер.

Comment: подскажите, где и как включить такие логи

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-logs.html